# frontend show edit profile with selected custom options

Tags: hooks, actions, profiles

So I have many custom user profile fields.

When I use `do_action( 'show_user_profile', $profileuser );` hook it displays all custom user profile fields..

But I would like to show only certain fields.

For example

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_extra_profile_fields1');

function add_extra_profile_fields1() {
    // add extra profile fields to user edit page
}

add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_extra_profile_fields2');

function add_extra_profile_fields2() {
    // add extra profile fields to user edit page
}
```

Now is there a way to display only `add_extra_profile_fields2` using `show_user_profile` hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either find the hook that is outputting all those extra fields and use `remove_action` on it.

Or you can just create your own hook:

```
do_action( 'my_theme_show_user_profile', $profile_user );
```